# Почему Node.js не видит файлы React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Есть 2 папки в корне проекта:

```
/build
/admin
```

В настройках express прописаны пути к файлам:

```
app.use('/admin', express.static('admin'))
app.use('/', express.static('build'))
```

При переходе по адресу `/admin` прогружается `index.html` из папки `admin`, но остальные файлы шаблона не прогружаются (`404` ошибка), так происходит только по адресу `/admin`. По адресу `/` нормально прогружается как `build` так и `admin` шаблоны. Почему так происходит?

Comment: "При переходе по адресу /admin прогружается index.html из папки admin, но остальные файлы шаблона файлы не прогружаются (404 ошибка)" так происходит потому, что в index.html неправильно прописано подключение всех сопутствующих файлов приложения "admin". посмотрите как подключается любой js|css - в пути ведь нет '/admin', по которому express знает какую именно статику выдать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается вот так:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/admin yarn run build
```